# JQuery document load issue on blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I am attempting to put a menu on my blogger page.  The menu has come from another source and I can verify it works by plugging into into a simple webpage.

Upon putting it in the HTML/Javascript gadget in blogger, it would not work.  I narrowed it down to the following section of code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //ajax menu? 

    if (typeof setting.contentsource=="object"){ //if external ajax menu 
        ddsmoothmenu.getajaxmenu($, setting)
    }
    else{ //else if markup menu 
     ddsmoothmenu.buildmenu($, setting) 
    }
})
```

Which never fires in blogger but does fire on my simple webpage.  Is this an issue with blogger?  Does blogger require some other event to be handled when the document is ready?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery(document).ready() you could try this:

```
$(function () { 

    if (typeof setting.contentsource=="object"){
        ddsmoothmenu.getajaxmenu($, setting)
    }

    else{ //else if markup menu 
     ddsmoothmenu.buildmenu($, setting) 
    }
});
```